# Flask SQLAlchemy with multiple foreign keys

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I wanna create a multiple foreign keys with same table or more.
e.g

```
class User(Base):
  __tablename__= 'user'
  ....
  create_uid = sa.Column(Integer, sa.ForeignKey('user.id')
  write_uid = sa.Column(Integer, sa.ForeignKey('user.id')
  tracability = sa.relationship('user', foreign_keys=[create_uid, write_uid])


class Foo(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'foo'
   .....
   create_uid = sa.Column(Integer, sa.ForeignKey('user.id')
   write_uid = sa.Column(Integer, sa.ForeignKey('user.id')
   tracability = sa.relationship('user', foreign_keys=[create_uid, write_uid])
```

Comment: See official manual. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths